# VHDL: Compare a n-bit string with don't cares to n values of STD_LOGIC variables

Tags: vhdl

How can I compare std_logic values

```
a,b,c,d : in STD_LOGIC;
```

with "01-0", which contains "don't care"?

A poor guess is

```
if (a,b,c,d) = "01-0" then ...
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: if you don't care about the value of `c`, why don't just omit it in the expression?

Comment: You could concatenate them into one 4 bit signal, and then compare.

Comment: Doesn't work how? And what tool? Provide a [mcve]. Your  if statement snippet is not analyzable as written. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.1 para 7 "The type of an aggregate shall be determinable solely from the context in which the aggregate appears, excluding the aggregate itself but using the fact that the type of the aggregate shall be a composite type. The type of an aggregate in turn determines the required type for each of its elements." The "=" can either be std_logic_vector or bit_vector here. Once past that use the -2008 matching equality operator (`?=`) or drop `c` from the expression.

Comment: VHDL 2008 has a "real" don't care equality operator (`?=`). Before that, you might get away with `std_match(...)`